# Vibration makes accelerometer give wrong values

Tags: android

I have simple app that reads acceleremoter values (for x,y and z axis). But for certain value i vibrate my phone programatically. So whenever vibration occurs accelerometer value flickers highly up and down in range. I want to avoid this. Please give me idea how to prevent accelerometer giving varying result when in vibration mode.

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

if (event.sensor.getType() != Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
return;          
         switch (mDisplay.getRotation()) {
                case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                    x = event.values[0];
                    y = event.values[1];
                    break;
                case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                    x = -event.values[1];
                    y = event.values[0];
                    Log.i("ROT: ", "90");
                    break;
                case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                    x = -event.values[0];
                    y = -event.values[1];
                    break;
                case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                    x = event.values[1];
                    y = -event.values[0];
                    break;
            }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a low pass filter, so that you can filtate the high shakings.
Something like this:

```
float lastAccel[] = new float[3];
float accelFilter[] = new float[3];
     accelFilter[0] = (float) (alpha * (accelFilter[0] + accelX - lastAccel[0]));
        accelFilter[1] = (float) (alpha * (accelFilter[1] + accelY - lastAccel[1]));
        accelFilter[2] = (float) (alpha * (accelFilter[2] + accelZ - lastAccel[2]));
```

Comment: Hi thanks for response. But i don't know how to implement it. I am very new to accelerometer stuff. From where am i getting accelFilter[0] values and finally how does it effect x, y and z values. Those x,y and z values are coming from event.values[0] etc. Sorry but i am confused.

Comment: accelFilter and lastAccel are empty variables...alpha is a coefficient between 0.1 and 0.9...i sugest to use 0.1...and accelX is your acceleration. in accelFilter[0] will be stored the new values of accelerometer.

Comment: hi i followed this url for pasing low filter but problem still occurs. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html Thanks

Comment: in case of vibration...you can make a mean fo accelerometer values, so that they will be more atenuated...any other solution i dont know...

Answer (score 0):

I think that you'll be forced to ignore acceleration values whilst vibrating the phone.

Comment: hi thanks. Could u elaborate it more. I just found the problem after hours that values flickers up and down only in vibration mode. How do i ignore acceleration values.