# Android: Prevent phone vibrate function from affecting accelerometer data

Tags: android, sensors, vibration

I've designed an app that tracks when I'm moving using the accelerometer, and may vibrate the phone depending on various thresholds I may have hit.  One of the issues I faced is that this vibration directly corrupts the accelerometer data.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8756244/3241079) answer suggested using a low pass filter, but I don't think that will work in this application (I need a relatively fast response time, and the vibrations cause large spikes in the data).

The solution I'm currently using is to set a flag to true right before the phone vibrates, call a `postDelayed` function that will set this back to false after a certain time (1 second in fine), and in the `onSensorChanged` function, simply return if the flag is true.

In other words:

```
isPhoneVibrating = true; // Start to vibrate     
phoneVibrator.vibrate(VibratePattern, -1);
mHandler.postDelayed(vibrateSensorOff, 1000); // 1 seconds wait before making false
```

The `vibrateSensorOff` only contains

```
isPhoneVibrating = false;
```

and like I said, in the `onSensorChanged` function I return if the flag `isPhoneVibrating` is true.

I don't like this solution because I need to manage this extra flag in the various states of this app.  Are there other possible solutions that don't require an extra flag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have two singletons that keep track if the phone is vibrating or not and manage the `Vibrator` and the `Accelerometer`.

The `Accelerometer` manager should expose the methods that you use for the `Accelerometer` and should pass on all events if the `Vibrator` isn't running (this is just like a filter for the accelerometer data). You should have an internal flag for if the phone is vibrating on the `Accelerometer` manager and methods to set it.

The `Vibrator` manager should expose the methods that you use for the `Vibrator` and should also update the `Accelerometer` manager's flag when the phone starts vibrating.

These are basically wrappers for the `Vibrator` and `Accelerometer` instances in your app, but they should allow you to use the `Accelerometer` without having to worry about the `Vibrator` flag everywhere in your app (only the manager objects should take care of that flag).

I know this solution does require an extra flag, but it allows you to manage that flag in just two places (in the two singletons) and you don't have to keep track of it in your entire app. If you do implement the two singletons, make sure that you don't use the `Vibrator` or `Accelerometer` directly (as you would have to keep track of the vibration flag to do that).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'll try this out tonight.  It seems like I would do something similar to what I already do (i.e. set the flag, then unset it a short while after), but with the benefit of hiding that operation in the singleton.